# Как можно оптимизировать pycharm

Tags: ide, pycharm, jetbrains

Дороу всем, существуют ли способы оптимизации pycharm под слабую железяку, чтобы меньше ресурсов поглощал? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Самое простое - меню File - Power Save Mode. Также для ускорения индексации установленных модулей лучше для проекта создавать отдельное виртуальное окружение.

Comment: 1) Стать главным в компании.
2) Уволить тех кто пишет на Java
3) Нанять тех кто пишет на С++
4) Заставить писать на С++ с нуля
5) Готово)

Ну а если серьезно - вопрос бредовый. Программа есть программа. Как ее написали так она и работает

Comment: @Данил надежда была, что это возможно.)

Comment: Сейчас бы рассказывать разработчикам лучших IDE как правильно делать IDE =)

Comment: @vp_arth вы это мне? Нет, нет, я очень благодарен jb за их прекрасные ide, и с удовольствием пользуюсь ими, но хотелось бы как-нибудь улучшить работу pycharm под слабое железо

Comment: Нет, это я Данилу с его с++, простите)

Comment: Ну на самом деле вопрос имеет смысл и я думаю, что если поиграться с некоторыми настройками и параметрами запуска, то можно чего-то да добиться.